# Problems with running f2py from terminal (Mac OSX)

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, f2py

This may seem to be a rather odd issue, but I have a fully functional Python with Numpy on my Mac, and the Numpy has f2py included in it. I can even access f2py by importing it explicitly on my iPython window as

```
from numpy import f2py
```

But I cannot run f2py from my terminal. Could someone suggest what to do?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly you have more than one python version/environment and are accessing different versions via ipython vs standard terminal?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to find where that f2py is that you can import in ipython: After importing f2py in ipython, just type f2py, and it should show you the location of the numpy installation. From that, you should be able to find the f2py binary.

For example, from within ipython, my f2py is in:

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/f2py/__init__.pyc
```

From here, we can see that the executable f2py will be in

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/f2py
```

As JohnE said, perhaps you have more than one python environment, and the one with f2py in it is not in your path?

Comment: On my system (Sierra) the executable is under `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/bin`